# difference between ListView and ArrayList

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist, sms

What is the difference between ListView and ArrayList and what should i choose when i develop  Chatting Activity using SMS  ?
 `ArrayList <Message>` and `ListView`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) is a general-purpose a data structure. It is not Android-specific. It looks something like this:

```
01011011001010110001010110110010101000100111011110001...
```

A [`ListView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) is an Android-only UI widget for displaying lists of things. It looks something like this:

[image]

In summary: RTFD.

Answer (score 1):

A Listview displays values

but a arraylist only provides a list of values (not showing the list)